# Trying to fix file parser

Tags: .net, vb.net, text, visual-studio-2012

So I work as a data analyst and it seems that the IT department never has time to code some of my projects so I decided to do it myself!  I made a pretty basic program that takes a source file (.csv) and moves around the column into the order I need.  It's working pretty well but I need help with a few things.

I am well aware that there may be a better way to do all of this.  I'm not 100% set with my code, especially if it can't do what I want below.

1. I'd like some sort of message box to pop up when the writer is done but I can't figure out how to do it.

   ```
   I figured out a way to do this.  I just added the revised code below.
   ```
2. I'd like to parse the zip codes using "-" as a delimiter and move everything after the "-" into the next column (so I can have zip and zip+4 as different columns).  As you can see, I tried to do something like that but it didn't work.  (Zip is in column 8)
3. I need to insert a header row with certain info.  I have no idea how to go about this!

   ```
   I figured this out too!  Edited the code below again.
   ```
4. I'd also like to change the date format around.  Source file is MM/DD/YYYY but I'd like to deliver as YYYYMMDD. (This would be columns 10 and 11)

So, here's the code I have so far.  It works pretty well but doesn't do all the stuff I'd like it to.

```
 Public Sub ParseButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ParseButton.Click

    ' Create the IEnumerable data source. 
    Dim lines As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FileInLocation).Skip(1).ToArray()
    Dim Date1 As Date = Date.Now

    Dim lineQuery = From line In lines
             Let x = line.Split(New Char() {","})
             Select "10010" & "," & (Date1.ToString("yyyyMMdd")) & "," &
              (Date1.ToString("yyyyMMdd")) & "," &
              "WY Mental Health Professions Licensing Board" & "," &
             "WY" & "," & x(4) & " " & "," & "," & x(1) & "," & x(2) & "," & x(0) & "," &
             x(5) & "," & "" & "," & x(6) & "," & x(7) & " " & "," & "," & x(8) & "," & " " & "," &
             x(3) & "," & x(9) & " " & "," & "," & x(10) & "," & x(11) & "," & x(12)

    ' Execute the query and write out the new file. Note that WriteAllLines 
    ' takes a string array, so ToArray is called on the query.

    Dim inputString As String = "DartID,DateAdded,DateUpdated,Website,State,BusinessName,DBA,NameFirst,NameMiddle,NameLast,NameSuffix,Address,AddressLine2,AddressCity,AddressState,AddressZipCode,Zip4,Email,LicenseNo,LicenseType,LicenseDateFrom,LicenseDateTo,LicenseStatus,"

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(FileOutLocation & "\Output.csv", inputString)

    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(FileOutLocation & "\Output.csv", Environment.NewLine)

    System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(FileOutLocation & "\Output.csv", lineQuery.ToArray())

    'Show message box on completion of file write

    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(FileOutLocation & "\Output.csv") Then
        MsgBox("Parse Complete!")
    Else
        MsgBox("Error, Parse Failed!")
    End If

End Sub
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Couple things.  1.  Each question should have its own post.  We don't like multi-question posts here at SO.  2.  You should really be using `Microsoft.Visualbasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`.  Eventually you will run up against a CSV that is not `String.Split()` friendly.

Comment: Sorry, first post here and I wasn't sure how to go about it.  I know that the source file will always be in the same format so, while you're correct that something might not be String.Split() friendly, I'm not worried about it with this particular file.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dates could be simply done like this DateTime.Parse(x(10)).ToString("yyyyMMdd")

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thanks so much, this was really a pain!

Answer (score 0):

I'd also like to change the date format around. Source file is MM/DD/YYYY but I'd like to deliver as YYYYMMDD. (This would be columns 10 and 11)

You can open temp string ,
eg:

```
    string *temp = Date1.tostring();
    string temp2[Date1.tostring().length] ;
```

and cope it

```
     temp2[0]=temp[4+2];
     temp2[1]=temp[5+2];
```

etc 
or run little for

```
     for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
     temp2[i]=temp[i+4+2];
```

same for days and monthes

dont forget to put the slashes after each format

sorry I dont know the syntax of this language but i bet you can figure it out .

Comment: I'm getting more and more familiar with how this file writer works so this may work, I just need to play with it.  Thanks!